# Missing \endcsname inserted when trying to make subtables

Tags: tables, errors, captions

I'm trying to make 2 subtables with 2 different captions inside of a table, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.9 \begin
          {tabular}{| r | r | r | r |}
?
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass [12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}

\begin{subtable}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{| r | r | r | r |}
\hline
    A & B & C & D \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption A}
\end{subtable}

\begin{subtable}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{| r | r | r | r |}
\hline
    A & B & C & D \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption B}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Caption of both A and B}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Stuff I read on google said that this error is usually caused by an extra `\` in an environment name, but I double checked and can't find any examples of this. Any solutions must work for the `report` document class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subtable` environment doesn't take a positioning optional argument like `table`, but wants instead a *mandatory* argument stating the width of the subtable.

You probably want something like

```
\documentclass [12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering

\begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{| r | r | r | r |}
\hline
    A & B & C & D \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption A}
\end{subtable}\hfil
\begin{subtable}{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| r | r | r | r |}
\hline
    A & B & C & D \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption B}
\end{subtable}

\caption{Caption of both A and B}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you should use `\centering` and not the `center` environment.